# Batch Clip (Editing Session)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, clip, topology

I'm trying to correct some topology errors in my geodatabase, now focusing on two feature classes: grass and buildings. They must not overlap. However, there are plenty of spaces where the grass was generalized, thus, covering entire buildings. There are no automatic fixes for this errors - unfortunately the subtract function deletes the overlapping part of both features, when I'd only like to delete the grass feature class and preserve the building feature class.

In this way, I'm using the "Clip..." function on the Editor Menu to use the buildings to cut out this portion of the grass. However, there's no way to select more than one building at a time to apply this function.

I cannot use the Erase Function from ArcToolBox, because the same inconsistence can happen also in the other way: generalized buildings covering grass areas. Also, I wouldn't like to have an output feature class, once I just need to change the shape of my features, nothing else.

**Is there any way I could use the "Clip..." function from the Editor Menu with multiple polygons, by selecting them all at a time?**

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this, at least partially, but I'm a little unclear about a couple things: are you looking for an automated way to decide what should be buildings and what should be grass or are you willing to do the work manually? Also, why not have an output feature class?  ArcGIS is designed to create backup after backup of everything via outputs like that.  You can get around it in python by overwriting outputs but in order to use the tools you have to at least create an interim output.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I'm willing to do the work manually, at least identifying where should be grass or building. However, I'd like to select multiple polygons to cut instead of doing one by one.

Creating an output wouldn't be a problem, I just think it wouldn't be necessary in this case. One way to go around this problem, I thought, would be to run the Erase tool just to the selected features. However, there's no such option. Right? Unless I create a new feature based on the previous selection.

Comment: If I were working on this project, that's exactly what I'd do--create a new feature based on the selection and then erase from the grass (or buildings).  It's not glamorous but it's fast.

Comment: Make a copy of your buildings layer. Select all of the buildings in the copy that you want to clip with and use the Editor Merge to make them a multipart feature. Now select that multipart feature and use the Editor Clip to clip the grass. This would save from having a bunch of layers from multiple building selections.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @mpianka you could:

> Make a copy of your buildings layer. Select all of the buildings in
>   the copy that you want to clip with and use the Editor Merge to make
>   them a multipart feature. Now select that multipart feature and use
>   the Editor Clip to clip the grass. This would save from having a bunch
>   of layers from multiple building selections.